# Why does my record not get added permanently to firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

As you can see, the document(
Dx1uGuXlK5XgVamF20XIfb3MoUs2
) is there, but it is displayed in grey and says=>: This document does not exist. It will not appear in queries or snapshots . If I decide to read this document, it does not exist because it is not "actually" there.

Here is my insert statement:

```
const db = fire.firestore().collection("User_Expenses");

  db.doc(currentUser.uid)
    .collection("expense")
    .add({
      Expense: "Default",
      ExpenseType: "Variable",
      Benefits: "none",
      Amount: "1000",
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Document successfully written!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is adding a document to a subcollection nested under the document with the user's UID.  If you click into the missing user document, you will find the document you added to the "expense" subcollection.

Firestore won't create "missing" documents in the path of nested document.  The console will simply show missing documents in italics as your screenshot illustrates.

If you want the user document to exist, you should decide what you want it to contain, then write more code to implement that.

```
fire.firestore()
    .collection("User_Expenses")
    .doc(currentUser.uid)
    .set({ field: "value" })
```

Comment: Thanks man, I figured it out a while back and first created the document before I added a object to a null document